# Google Play Books - Navigate back to reading passage text

Tags: navigation, ebooks, google-play-books, reading

Often in ebooks there are links embedded in paragraphs that reference some image or figure in the previous chapters or sections. Once I've clicked on it (and viewed that image), how do I get back to the paragraph I was reading?

Hitting android's back button always exits the app.

Comment: whic ebook reader are you using?

Comment: Its google play books.

Comment: Well you can use other ebook reader like aldiko

Comment: But I've purchased some books via play books...

Comment: Tell if it is working, I can make that as answer

Comment: Downloaded epub as suggested. I got file with extension `*.acsm`. Installed the app too. Tried to import the file. Got error saying device not authorized...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return to the last page you visited, you can just tap on the screen to notice a bar in the bottom. If you look closer you can see a blue triangle that marks the last visited page. Click on it and you'll return to that page!

[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Okay. I notice this in tablet or phones. But there is nothing in the web version of the app to the same effect, I suppose.

Comment: ...aren't you talking about using Google Play Books on a tablet or phone?

Comment: I wanted it for both actually, but I guess the latter is a question for a different stackexchange.

Comment: This functionality no longer exists.

Comment: @deostroll I noticed that the page information is stored in the URL on web. So going back to the previously visited page is as simply as using the Go back arrow in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

To return to the previous location just tap the centre of the screen to bring up page navigation and then click the back button.

Note: looks like the previous functionality of a blue triangle has been removed.